# DIV blocks displaying incorrectly in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, html

So I figured out the NAV bar and got it working in IE but the DIV blocks still display incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here are the css files:**

[www.dmstriping.com/new site/css/style.css](http://www.dmstriping.com/new%20site/css/style.css)
[www.dmstriping.com/new site/css/layout.css](http://www.dmstriping.com/new%20site/css/layout.css)

Web Site:
www.dmstriping.com/new site/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using HTML5 elements but with the HTML4.01 doctype. Second, IE<9 does not understand the new elements without javascript help which you might be using some sort going by your code. In any case, validate your html and css for those lists of errors and let us know if this is working in the modern browsers (anything but IE).